# select index of listView is not working in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, listview, html, ado.net, eval

I am new to ASP.NET, I am making a search box in my application.

For example: if a user enters "abc" in the textbox, then the textbox will fetch data from the database which starts with "abc".  I am passing this data to `DataTable`.

It works properly,

Here is my code snippet:

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConsString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();

    string query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT Scrip FROM dbo.SearchBoxData where Scrip Like '{0}%'", TextBox1.Text);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    conn.Close();

    lvwItems.DataSource = result;
    lvwItems.DataBind();
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all this data in my `<div>` tag. so i tried using  `asp:ListView`,

here is my code snippet,

**it works properly, but now i want to navigate to new page when user select any row of listView, but i am unable to select any row..**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwItems" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plhItems">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div>
         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhItems" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        <%# Eval("Scrip")%>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Thanks In Advance !!**

***Any help will be appreciated.***

EDIT:(SearchBox.aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class SearchBox : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connString;
    DataTable result = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConsString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        string query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT Scrip FROM dbo.SearchBoxData where Scrip Like '{0}%'", TextBox1.Text);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        conn.Close();

        lvwItems.DataSource = result;
        lvwItems.DataBind();
    }



    protected void lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lvwItems.Items[e.NewSelectedIndex];
        Label lablId = (Label)item.FindControl("lablId");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lablId.Text))
        {
            Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx?id=" + lablId.Text, false);
        }
    }
```

(SearchBox.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SearchBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="SearchBox" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    </head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="179px" 
        OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" 
        Width="62px" />
    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


  <asp:ListView ID="lvwItems" OnSelectedIndexChanging="lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging" 
 runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plhItems">
 <LayoutTemplate>
  <div>
       <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhItems" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
  </div>
 </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div>
 <%# Eval("Scrip")%>
    <asp:Label ID="lablId" visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Scrip") %>'/>

  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:krunal_DBConnectionString2 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SearchBoxData]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, `lvwItems.DataSource = result;
        lvwItems.DataBind();` it works properly, just i want selected index of row. how should i ?

Comment: Add Select button to listView

Comment: it is necessary to add ? (but i don't want to add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a SELECT button in the ItemTemplate, see the complete working code.

```
  <asp:ListView ID="lvwItems" OnSelectedIndexChanging="lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging"
    runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plhItems">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhItems" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Scrip")%>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>

protected void lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs  e)
{
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lvwItems.Items[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    Label lablId = (Label)item.FindControl("CONTROL_ID");
}
```

Thanks

Deepu

Comment: instead of adding `<asp:LinkButton>` i tried using `<asp:Button>` it's working now. thanx for the help.

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="btn1" BackColor="White"  BorderStyle="None" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Scrip") %>' OnClick="callMethod" />`

Comment: if i want to get text of selected button thn how should i get... this is my last question.. (ans this and i will accept your ans)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to add the event for Selected index change:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwItems" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plhItems" OnSelectedIndexChanging="lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging">
```

Comment: sorry i meant onselectedindexchanged..Anyways is the data showing up?

Answer (score 0):

In code behind you can get the selected row item like below.

Also you can place a label or hidden field so that you can get some data from those control and pass it in to the next page.. (might be id or something).

```
   <asp:ListView ID="lvwItems" OnSelectedIndexChanging="lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging" 
 runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plhItems">
 <LayoutTemplate>
  <div>
       <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhItems" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
  </div>
 </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div>
    <%# Eval("Scrip")%>
     <asp:Label ID="lablId" visible="flase" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

 void lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
 {
   ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lvwItems.Items[e.NewSelectedIndex];
   Label lablId = (Label)item.FindControl("lablId");

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lablId.Text))
   {
     Response.Redirect("page.aspx?id="+lablId.Text,false);
   }
 }
```

Thanks

Deepu

Comment: `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(l.Text))` what is this, how to call this method ?

Comment: data is coming properly but `lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging` is not getting fired in aspx.cs file

Comment: chk my code, here.. `http://pastebin.com/3WBsZS8C` , `http://pastebin.com/V13r2zSi`

Comment: I am unable to access the link, can you paste the code here itself ?

Comment: krunal - I have posted the working code, let me know if its working for you

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

Also remove the OnClick="callMethod" from the button. Since you have SelectedIndex method no need to have the onClick method.

```
protected void lvwItems_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs  e)
{
  ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lvwItems.Items[e.NewSelectedIndex];
  Button btn = (Button)item.FindControl("btn1");
  if(btn != null) 
  {
   var buttonText = btn.Text;  
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Thanks

Deepu